# cellfun name-value pair with name 'un'?

Tags: matlab

At a [Matlab Central question](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/878-how-do-i-convert-strings-stored-in-a-cell-array-to-numbers), I saw the following syntax for converting a series of strings to numbers:

```
c = {'Name' '2/8' '3/7' '7/8'}
[c(1); cellfun(@str2num,c(2:end),'un',0).']
```

From mucking with the code, I found that the dot near the end is unnecessary.  However, I haven't found any documentation on the meaning of the cellfun name-value pair named 'un'.  This is both in the 2015b documentation on the web and my native 2015a doc pages, looking under both cellfun and str2num.  Would anyone be able to shed some light on that?

And on a *very* related question, I found the above while trying to find a code idiom for converting a table variable from string to numerical (perhaps with NaN for nonumerical entries).  What is the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: `'un',0` is probably a shortening of `'uniformoutput',false`. That's needed if the output for various cell elements differs in size; in this case the output is a cell array instead of a matrix.

Comment: `'un'` is actually `'UniformOutput'`, but MATLAB allows you to specify name-value things using only enough letters to be a unique reference to the option. It can make for confusing code, as you've found!

Comment: Actually `'` means hermitian conjugate in Matlab. This is the same as transpose + elementwise complex conjugate. The normal token for this star or dagger, but since dagger is non ascii and star means multiplication there must be some other notation in matlab. Thus is `'` considered hermitian conjugate and and `.'` means transpose. For real numbers you will not notice the difference.

Comment: Hmm.  OK, interesting.  Nice to know (though I haven't dealt with complex numbers since....decades).  I think it can be pared away for the purpose of this example.  The entries were real, and the intent was to show how to convert strings to numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Andras Deak & David for explaining that the 'un' name-value pair is actually the short name for the 'UniformOutput' name-value pair.

As for the 2nd part of the question in the original post, str2double(myTable.myStringVariableColumnName) seems to work fine.