# matlab shorthand forms for coding

Tags: matlab

I noticed there are allowed abbreviations for code in Matlab. E.g.

```
cellfun('isempty',magic(5),'Uni',0); %instead of
cellfun('isempty',magic(5),'Uniformoutput',0);
```

or

```
disp('asdf'); %instead of
display('asdf');
```

which saves time and is more convenient. Is there a list of or resource to find out about shorthand commands available online (like a cheatsheet)? I could not find such a resource and stumbled upon these examples more or less by chance.

Thanks

Comment: `disp('asdf');` is not a short form of  `display('asdf');`  These are different functions. They just seem to be working like that because of the example that you chose. try with `A=rand(3);` `disp(A)`; `display(A);` Asking us for resource is offtopic for SO

Comment: All properties can be shortened as long as the truncation leaves it unambiguous. I.e. you can even use just `'U'` if there is no other property accepted with that name.

Comment: @MadPhysicist is it all now? When I stopped using Matlab about 2 years ago, some functions still used an old input parser not supporting the shortened argument names.

Comment: @Daniel. All may be an overstatement, but they've been doing a good job clearing away the old parser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cellfun name-value pair with name 'un'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077549/cellfun-name-value-pair-with-name-un)

Comment: It helps everyone get programming done faster and therefore highly relevant for everyone using Matlab. Unsure why the off-topic close, it seems a tad random. Where is a better place for this than here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

First of all, `disp` and `display` are two different functions. `disp` is the function you use to display a variable, `display` is the function internally called, whenever a line does not end with a semicolon. Always and only use `disp`.

About the shortened input parameter names like `UniformOutput` or `uni`, whenever a function uses the [inputparser](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop) or similar, you can abbreviate. This is explained in the PartialMatch section, it will per default match any leading substring. Most bot not all functions support it.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote.

Comment: btw how is using `disp` better? Can you quote any reason or reference for that?

Comment: @SardarUsama the documentations says so. Check `doc disp` or `doc display`. I don't see any reason to evaluate the undocumented use of `display` unless there is a possible advantage.

Comment: I couldn't find any such thing in the doc that recommends the use of `disp` and depreciates the use of `display`. Would you please pinpoint it? btw `display` is not an undocumented function

Comment: It is a undocumented use. The documentation says "Used internally for command-window display". The function is intended to be used for a different purpose.

Comment: I wouldn't have expected Mathworks to document it in the first place if its use was unrecommended. Anyway

Comment: @Daniel. Adding links in your answer would make it even better.

Comment: I have contacted Mathworks Technical Support regarding this matter and they have clearly said that the use of `display` just like `disp` is perfectly fine and isn't depreciated. (cc: @MadPhysicist)